# Remove duplicated code - using Action

Tags: c#, delegates, action

I have the following code which obviously has some duplication. I'm sure this could be removed using a delegate or Action but can't quite grasp it.

anyone got any ideas?

```
public void DealStartingCards()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                foreach (var player in Players)
                {
                    if (player.Hand.FaceDownCards.Count < 3)
                    {
                        if (Deck.Count > 0) 
                        player.Hand.FaceDownCards.Add(Deck.TakeTopCard());
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                foreach (var player in Players)
                {
                    if (player.Hand.FaceUpCards.Count < 3)
                    {
                        if (Deck.Count > 0) 
                        player.Hand.FaceUpCards.Add(Deck.TakeTopCard());
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                foreach (var player in Players)
                {
                    if (player.Hand.InHandCards.Count < 3)
                    {
                        if (Deck.Count > 0) 
                        player.Hand.InHandCards.Add(Deck.TakeTopCard());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

InHandCards, FaceUpCards and FaceDownCards are all of type `List<Card>`

Comment: Why are all the `if` conditions necessary? Don't you start off with a full-deck and empty hands for all the players?

Comment: yes, but it is possible to deal all of the cards out if there are enough players so need to check if the deck is empty. guess this check might be better placed in the deck object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking Oskar's solution and changing it slightly:

```
private void DealCards(Func<Hand, List<Card>> handProjection)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        foreach (var player in Players)
        {
            List<Card> cards = handProjection(player.Hand);
            if (cards.Count < 3)
            {
                if (Deck.Count > 0) 
                {
                    cards.Add(Deck.TakeTopCard());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void DealStartingCards()
{
    DealCards(hand => hand.FaceDownCards);
    DealCards(hand => hand.FaceUpCards);
    DealCards(hand => hand.InHandCards);
}
```

(That's assuming the type of `player.Hand` is `Hand` - adjust accordingly otherwise, of course.)

Comment: I like this one. Did not know you could use that kind of methods :)

Comment: this is what I was after. Just need to get my head round understanding it now. I was convinced an Action was what was required coz there wouldn't be a return value. Just performing some action on each of the parts of the Hand

Comment: @Christo: Well, for each of the parts of the hand you need to check the count *and* add to it. It's simpler to just return that part of the hand as a list. You *could* do it in other ways, but I think this is the simplest.

Comment: OK - so what does the handProjection parameter represent? I'm struggling to understand how this works

Comment: I can see handProjection is a delegate that takes a hand and returns a list<Card>. Just struggling to see how the code flows. this is my limited grasp of delegates I guess.

Comment: the lamda is instructing which List<Card> to return? is that correct? i.e saying which part of the hand we do the subsequent action on

Comment: @Christo: Sorry for the delay - yes, the delegate says which cards to fetch from a given hand. Using different lambda expressions means you can add cards to different bits of the hand.